# Find percentage ratio within sum values in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of retail transactions in a SQL table. The table contains details for the customer number, product number, transaction type, transaction date and amount.

Ultimately, I need to produce a record that contains the customer number, product number, transaction type, sum of transaction amounts and a %. The percentage represents what proportion of all transactions for that customer/product combination were of that given transaction type.

For example my table has data like this:

```
╔══════════╦═════════╦═════════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║ Customer ║ Product ║ TxnType ║  TxnDate   ║ TxnAmount ║
╠══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║ Smith    ║    1234 ║ Cash    ║ 01/01/2018 ║        10 ║
║ Smith    ║    1234 ║ Credit  ║ 02/01/2018 ║        20 ║
║ Smith    ║    1234 ║ Cash    ║ 03/01/2018 ║        10 ║
║ Smith    ║    1234 ║ Cash    ║ 04/01/2018 ║        20 ║
║ Smith    ║    3456 ║ Cash    ║ 01/01/2018 ║        10 ║
║ Smith    ║    3456 ║ Credit  ║ 02/01/2018 ║        20 ║
║ Smith    ║    3456 ║ Cash    ║ 03/01/2018 ║        10 ║
║ Jones    ║    3456 ║ Credit  ║ 01/01/2018 ║        10 ║
║ Jones    ║    3456 ║ Cash    ║ 02/01/2018 ║        10 ║
║ Jones    ║    3456 ║ Credit  ║ 01/01/2018 ║        20 ║
║ Jones    ║    1234 ║ Credit  ║ 01/01/2018 ║        10 ║
║ Jones    ║    1234 ║ Credit  ║ 02/01/2018 ║        20 ║
║ Jones    ║    1234 ║ Credit  ║ 03/01/2018 ║        20 ║
║ Jones    ║    1234 ║ Credit  ║ 04/01/2018 ║        40 ║
╚══════════╩═════════╩═════════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

And I need a result of this:

```
╔══════════╦═════════╦═════════╦══════════════╦════════════╗
║ Customer ║ Product ║ TxnType ║ SumTxnAmount ║ %ofTxnType ║
╠══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬════════════╣
║ Smith    ║    1234 ║ Cash    ║           40 ║ 66%        ║
║ Smith    ║    1234 ║ Credit  ║           20 ║ 33%        ║
║ Smith    ║    3456 ║ Cash    ║           20 ║ 50%        ║
║ Smith    ║    3456 ║ Credit  ║           20 ║ 50%        ║
║ Jones    ║    3456 ║ Cash    ║           10 ║ 25%        ║
║ Jones    ║    3456 ║ Credit  ║           30 ║ 75%        ║
║ Jones    ║    1234 ║ Credit  ║           90 ║ 100%       ║
╚══════════╩═════════╩═════════╩══════════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=715cb4374ccc51a8fd4a68199f40c3f2)

```
select 
  customer,product,TxnType,
  sum(TxnAmount) as SumTxnAmount,cast((sum(TxnAmount)*100.00)/(select 
  sum(TxnAmount) from cte1 b where a.customer=b.customer and a.product=b.product) as decimal(16,2)) as '%ofTxnType'
```

from cte1 a
group by customer,product,TxnType

OUTPUT:

```
customer    product TxnType  SumTxnAmount   %ofTxnType
Smith       1234    Cash      40              66.67
Smith       1234    Credit    20              33.33
```